# Using awk to select column data from separate files

Tags: awk

I am not an experienced Linux user. I am trying to select column data from 2 separate files and write to a third file using awk. I have tried to paste the files together i.e. paste file1 file2 and then awk but the data is appended on the next line (alternating).

The data looks like this:

file1

```
HZ880   0.00 

HAM86   1.13 

HAM40   1.60
```

file2

```
HZ880  -31.816826 115.757963   35.8909  0.0170  -.0170

HAM86  -31.824923 115.761507   33.6108  0.0165  -.0165

HAM40  -31.828528 115.762380   38.8434  0.0163  -.0163
```

How do I create a new file with column2 (file1) and column4 (file2)?

I have tried the following:

```
paste ${LEV_IN1} ${LEV_IN2} | awk '{print $2,$4}' > ${TEMP2}
```

where `LEV_IN1` is file1 and `LEV_IN2` is file2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

When you give file names one after another first it count all the columns from file1 and then start counting from next number to the file2. That means it counts 2 columns of file1 and start column 3,4,5.... and so on of the file2.

To get the column 4 of the file2 you need to write `$6` because command start counting from 3 in file2.

This will give you the desire output (change `$6` with other number if you mean to print anyother column from file2):

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $2 " " $6}' > outputfile.txt
```

---

Another way (Here `$4` means column 4 of the file2):

```
paste <(awk '{print $2}' file1) <(awk '{print $4}' file2) > outputfile.txt
```

Output:

```
0.00    35.8909

1.13    33.6108

1.60    38.8434
```

---

Following is the pure `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$2; next} {print a[FNR], $4}' file1 file2 > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses. When I try this, the data is correct until line 10 when the columns start being written to separate lines

Comment: Pure awk is  `awk '{printf "%s ", $2;getline <"file2";print $4}' file1`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `awk` for the task

```
join --nocheck-order -o 1.2,2.4 file1 file2
```

or

```
paste file1 file2 | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f2,6
```